# Showing selectable and non-selectable row in a grid

Tags: grid, ordering

I have a grid where I need to show to differentiate 2 kind of rows, ones that can be selected and others that cannot. All the rows include a link and the user can select multiple rows.

My question is regarding to the sorting of the rows. My first thought is that they should be order alphabetically, but then i realize that maybe is would be easier to the user if the rows are order by state: the ones that can not be selected will be grouped together ( will be at max of 3 rows).

Which is the better approach?
[image]

Comment: Can the user change the order? Can they sort on different columns? Are there any headers?

Comment: @DarrylGodden Yes. There will be headers for changing sort. One for status too.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing the user and the workflow. Is it typical that the user would usually only be interested in selectable items?

Comment: Why do you need grouping between selectable and the one that is not clickable? What is the use case?

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to have some background info on your problem e.g. how does a user arrive at these rows? Search? What do the states mean for the user i.e. what task would they want to be achieving/do they use selectable ones more or non selectables?

In any case, here are some general solutions:

- If you don't have too many records, you can simply split the page into two columns, selectable ones and non-selectable ones.
- You can order by Alphabet for the selectable ones only and above the rows include a checkbox to "Show selectable ones". Make sure users don't miss this though!

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @razzer-bake , sorry for my lack of explanation. The grid  appears associate to an record. Is intend to show related elements - ones can be selected because are applied locally, other can not be change because are applied by default to all records and can not be removed.  I want to keep both  in the same grid because the section is called “ applied elements”

Answer (score 1):

In a comment to another answer it seems that you want to be able to show a list of associated items with the ability to select more.

If this is the case I would keep the alphabetical sorting (or whatever sorting matters) but in the pre-associated rows display a checkmark indicating that they are already linked.

Finally if the associated items are editable (e.g. The association can be broken) then the result list should reflect the state of the relationship and thus the associated rows should be pre-checked checkboxes.